# How to exclude dynamic set tags in RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework

Good day for all. I try to exclude dynamic tags but cant reach my goal. What am I doing wrong?

waidw.robot:

```
# -*- coding=utf-8 -*-
# -*- coding=robot -*-

*** Settings ***
Test Template  My Awesome Keyword
*** Test Cases ***
Case 1  hello  hello  Smoke  Manual
Case 2  world  world  Auto

*** Keywords ***
My Awesome Keyword 
    [Arguments]  ${Alpha}  ${Betta}  @{Tags}
    Set tags  @{Tags}
    Should be equal  ${Alpha}  ${Betta}
```

from shell:

```
$ pybot -d ./result --non-critical Auto --exclude Auto wiadw.robot
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot include or exclude tests for dynamic tags. When pybot (or equivalent) starts up, it parses all of the code and builds up a list of tests to run before it runs any tests at all. This list of tests doesn't change as tests are run. Plus, in order for a dynamic tag to be set, the test has to start running. It's too late to exclude it at that point.

In other worlds, `--include` and `--exclude` can only work on static tags that are part of the test before the tests run.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup   Dynamic Tags Setup

*** Test Cases ***
First test case
      Log   This test will not be skipped

Second test case
      [Setup]  Skipping Setup
      Log   This line will be skipped if Auto tag is set

*** Keywords ***
Dynamic Tags Setup
    Set Tags    Auto

Skipping Setup
    Skip If  "Auto" in ${TEST TAGS}    Skipped due to Auto tag
```